# NullPointerException upon using ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

In the given code below, I get a `NullPointerException` when I include the ***for block*** so as to use the ***ArrayList words*** in the ArrayAdapter constructor. However, if I remove the ***for block*** and instead use the ***String array strArray***, it works just fine.

Could anyone tell me why is that so?

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

 public class ShowList extends SherlockListFragment 
 {
    private static final String[] strArray={"this","one","is","an","experimental","list"};
    ArrayList<String> words; 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    for(String s: strArray)
    {

        words.add(s);

    }

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,words);
    Log.d("Action","before setListAdapter"); 
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The code that works fine is below:

```
 public class ShowList extends SherlockListFragment 
 {
     private static final String[] strArray={"this","one","is","an","experimental","list"};
    ArrayList<String> words; 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

/*  for(String s: strArray)
    {

        words.add(s);

    }
*/
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strArray);
    Log.d("Action","before setListAdapter"); 
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the object words.

```
words= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

`words` is unitialized, but you add objects to it.

You must do

```
words = new ArryList<String>();
```

before you enter the loop.

And I would get used to declare such a variable as

```
List<String>words
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<String>words.
```

`List` is in interface, and you can pass arbitrary lists to other functions, but if you specify `ArrayList` specifically, you can only pass that kind of lists. For this exmaple it doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize you ArrayList words; first:

```
private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And also

```
private static final String[]strArray{"this","one","is","an","experimental","list"};
```

seems not compiled. change it to:

```
private static final String[] strArray =  {"this", "one", "is", "an", "experimental", "list"};
```

Comment: oo.... thanks . the second issue was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out..I've made the necessary changes. ..